# How do you retreve additional Information from the Facebook Registration Plugin?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

This has got to be easy but, using the Facebook C# SDK how do I retrieve the additional information requested by the registration plugin?

I want to retrieve the Favourite_animal value.

Here is the Java script for the plugin.

```
  <script>
      FB.init({
          appId: '123123123123123', cookie: true,
          status: true, xfbml: true
      });
  </script>
     <fb:registration
        fields="[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'},
        {'name':'Favourite_Animal','description':'What is your favourite animal?',
        'type':'text'}]" redirect-uri="http://XXXXXX.com/FacebookAuth2/Account/Home">
</fb:registration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I am new to this libray but it does not look like you can retrieve those values. I made some changes to the Facebook.dll Specifiacally in the Facebook.FacebookSignedRequest class I added the last 6 lines of code in this snippet below which is from the constructor for the class. The bottom line creates a public property "Registration" and the lines above it put the data in the field.

```
 public FacebookSignedRequest(IDictionary<string, object> value)
    {
        this.UserId = value.ContainsKey("user_id") ? (string)value["user_id"] : null;
        this.AccessToken = value.ContainsKey("oauth_token") ? (string)value["oauth_token"] : null;
        this.Expires = value.ContainsKey("expires") ? DateTimeConvertor.FromUnixTime(Convert.ToInt64(value["expires"])) : DateTime.MinValue;
        this.IssuedAt = value.ContainsKey("issued_at") ? DateTimeConvertor.FromUnixTime(Convert.ToInt64(value["issued_at"])) : DateTime.MinValue;
        this.ProfileId = value.ContainsKey("profile_id") ? (string)value["profile_id"] : null;
        this.Algorithm = value.ContainsKey("algorithm") ? (string)value["algorithm"] : null;

        if (value.ContainsKey("user"))
        {
            var user = (IDictionary<string, object>)value["user"];
            this.User = new FacebookSignedRequestUser
            {
                Country = value.ContainsKey("country") ? (string)user["country"] : null,
                Locale = value.ContainsKey("locale") ? (string)user["locale"] : null,
            };
        }

        if (value.ContainsKey("registration"))
        {
            this.Registration = (IDictionary<string, object>)value["registration"];
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets th key value pairs from the Registration plugin input fields. Accessibile even if user chooses not to use Facebook for registration
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string, object> Registration { get; set; }
```

Now what ever fields I add into the Registration Plugin I can access by name. Hopefully this will help some one else. Feel free to post a better idea as well.

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();

        Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer(app);
        if (authorizer.Authorize())
        {
            object returnValue;
            app.SignedRequest.Registration.TryGetValue("Fovourite_Animal", out returnValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the additional information from the registration plugin using the latest version of the Facebook C# SDK.

Simply call the static method Parse on the `FacebookSignedRequest` class as shown below (with your app secret, and the signed request):

```
var DecodedSignedRequest = FacebookSignedRequest.Parse(FacebookContext.Current.AppSecret, SignedRequest);
```

Now you will see all the data from the signed request in `DecodedSignedRequest`, including the registration plugin data as JSON objects.